# puts(address of stack) does not print the string pointed by the address

Tags: reverse-engineering, rop

I am trying to do ROP using gadget chaining technique on a 64-bit machine.

This is the source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char * str = "Hello World!";
    char buf[4];
    puts(str);
    gets(buf);

}
```

The code is compiled with `-fno-stack-protector -no-pie` and `ASLR is turned off` on the system as well.

Here is the disassembly of the binary:
[image]

I want to print a string of my choice using gadget chaining. I plan to do this using puts and I found the relevant gadgets for the same.
[image]

`puts` needs an address which is pointing to a string terminated with NULL. So I put my string on the buffer followed by a NULL and then overwrite the RET address with `pop rdi;ret` which is then followed by the value I want to put into RDI register. From the code, I found the address of the buffer and gave that address as input. So, now rdi contains the address to buffer. But when I call puts I am not getting any output.

Below are the value of registers before puts is called(using gadget).
[image]

`x/s address of buffer` gives me the string I passed in as input

On changing the address of rdi from the buffer to the string within the code I am able to see HelloWorld getting printed twice.

Here is the payload:
[image]

Here is the output:
[image]

What goes wrong when the address is pointing to the stack? Is it not possible to print something that is already on the stack?